# Existence of solution to a matrix inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and $\mathbf G\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric, positive definite, non-singular matrix. Let $\mathbf c\in\mathbb R^{n}$ be an arbitrary vector. Does there exist a vector $\mathbf a\in\mathbb R^n$ that solves the following system:

- $\mathbf a\geq \mathbf 0$;
- $\mathbf G\mathbf a\geq \mathbf c$;
- $\mathbf a^{\text{T}}\mathbf G\mathbf a=\mathbf a^{\text{T}}\mathbf c$?

Could, say, Farkas's lemma be of use here?

Comment: What do you mean by $a\geq0$? Do you mean all it's components would be greater then $0$?

Comment: @Mastrel Yes, $a_i\geq0$ for each $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: Observation: $a^T(Ga-c)=0$ means that either the $i$th component of $Ga-c=0$ or $a_i=0$

Comment: @MehdiJafarniaJahromi So you get $a_i=0$ or $a_i = (G^{-1}c)_i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a unique vector $a$ that solves the problem.

**Proof:** Here is a proof from convex optimization. Your system can be rephrased as the following:

$$
0 \leq a \perp Ga-c \geq 0
$$
This is in fact KKT conditions for solving the following optimization problem:

$$
\min_{a\geq 0} \frac{1}{2}a^TGa -c^Ta
$$
Since $G$ is positive definite, this quadratic function is strictly convex and has a unique solution. Moreover, we know that there is a minimizer $a$ of this optimization problem if and only if it satisfies the KKT conditions. So there is a unique $a$ that satisfies the system.

Comment: That's a clever approach. I have a concern, however. If you denote the vector of multipliers as $\mathbf m$, then the first-order conditions read as follows:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf G\mathbf a-\mathbf c+\mathbf m=&\,\mathbf0,\\
\mathbf m^{\text{T}}\mathbf a=&\,\mathbf0,\\
\mathbf m\geq&\,\mathbf0,\\
\mathbf a\geq&\,\mathbf0.
\end{align*}
Now, these easily imply that $\mathbf a^{\text T}\mathbf G\mathbf a=\mathbf c^{\text T}\mathbf a$, but also that $\mathbf G\mathbf a-\mathbf c=-\mathbf m$, and $-\mathbf m$ is a _non-positive_ vector, yet I need $\mathbf G\mathbf a\geq\mathbf c$.

Comment: Never mind. With a minimization problem at hand, the relevant condition is $\mathbf m\leq\mathbf 0$. This makes your solution fully valid, I think. Thank you, much appreciated.